# Safari calculates height of the columns differently from other browsers

Tags: html, css, safari, html-table

I have a table with the following layout:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3" class="first-column">1. First column</th>
      <th class="top-cell">1. Second column</th>
      <th class="top-cell">1. Third column</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="bottom-cell">2. Second column</th>
      <th class="bottom-cell">2. Third column</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="bottom-cell">3. Second column</th>
      <th class="bottom-cell">3. Third column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

css:

```
table .first-column {
  height: 200px;
}
```

`th` tag with `.first-column` class always has fixed height. `.bottom-cell` can have also fixed height if it's needed (and I already tried this approach, but it didn't solve the issue). `top-cell` must have dynamic height.

And this table displays as I want in Firefox and Chrome: height of the columns is set proportional to each other.

But Safari display it differently, it just set height to the first two column by content and stretch last row to fill remaining space. But I want to accomplish one of this results:

[image]
[image]

Is there any workaround to display columns in Safari as Firefox or Chrome do? I know how to do it with js, so I'm looking for a solution with pure css.

I already tried to set fixed height for the `.bottom-cell`:

```
table .bottom-cell {
  height: 20px;
}
```

I also tried to combine fixed height of the `.bottom-cell` with `calc` function for `.top-cell`:

```
table .bottom-cell {
  height: 20px;
}

table .top-cell {
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

---

[Demo on plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/94MisMfp6ZRnFiYT3hSz?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Problems**

There are three separate, but important things to consider with your issue.

1. Setting an explicit height on your `.first-column` is the primary culprit for the why your table is not being displayed correctly.
2. Relying on the browser to properly space out your elements is tricky at best. Let's not forget we haven't even considered into how the various versions of IE displays your table.
3. The way you currently have your table structured isn't semantically correct as you have all your data in a `<thead>` and everything is considered a header for your data (i.e., `<th>` instead of `<td>`). So make sure you update your table with the correct tags.

**The Solution**

It's common for developers to try and account for every scenario (i.e., tables that can accommodate any amount of text) in their designs, but it is ultimately impractical and usually results in subpar design / code consistency.

So, my recommendation to you is to set explicit heights on your data (which will inadvertently set the height on your `.first-column`) in order to provide a more consistent viewing experience on different browsers.

**Code ([Demo](http://codepen.io/BenCodeZen/pen/PPNLOL))**

HTML

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">1. First column</td>
      <td>1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ea sed, incidunt adipisci amet ullam quae rem dignissimos aspernatur consequatur animi perferendis esse. Assumenda a voluptates deleniti officiis nobis consequuntur.</td>
      <td>1. Porro obcaecati assumenda quae reiciendis at et, laudantium animi perferendis itaque corporis esse illo, alias eius, fugiat temporibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit commodi nihil, ex esse delectus vero libero, dignissimos iure aliquam voluptate id ab perferendis sapiente tempora. Voluptatem, perferendis ducimus in sit?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="static-data">2. Second column</td>
      <td class="static-data">2. Third column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="static-data">3. Second column</td>
      <td class="static-data">3. Third column</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
  width: 400px;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.static-data {
  height: 80px;
}
```

**Update**

The code above has been updated to reflect your requirements below in the comments. The first row is now dynamic while the rest of the content has a set fixed height.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 1. Luckily I don't need to support IE. 2. I just didn't add `tbody` section because it isn't related to this issue. First column at the first row always has fixed height. I also tried to set fixed height for `td` in last two `tr` tags, but it also didn't help. I see that I didn't provide enough information. I'm going to update my answer, so it becomes more clear.

Comment: @fakerun I've updated my answer with a demo and code sample to show you how the table should be defined in order for it to appear properly in all three browsers. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I know that it will works in this case.  But I can't set fixed height for all `td` tags, because `td.top-cell` in first row is dynamic and can have any height. Each column in first row contains not only text, but also a lot of data and I put only text just to keep simple my question. To clarify: I can set fixed height for all `td` expect `td.top-cell`.

Comment: Not a problem. As you can see in my updated answer, the key is to only set a height on the cells that are considered static data. Once you do that, the browser will take care of the rest.

Comment: I have no idea why I didn't try to do it in the following way. Thank you for the clarification!